# ; character ;when ;I ;press ;the ;spacebar

Tags: keyboard

Also tf when I press t. hg when I press h. gh for g. I was on 17 and everything was working fine. I had to edit what I typed.

otfffherwise ;itff ;will ;come ;outf ;liked ;tffhis.

Any idea as to what it could be?

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard?

Comment: This is my laptop. Once I plug a keyboard in there is no problem.

Comment: You got the latest drivers?

Comment: I think your laptop keyboard is busted-I had something similar when I spilled fluid over it. Best to just replace.

Comment: This definitely sounds like hardware issues.  If the issue goes away when you use an external keyboard, then I'd point at hardware as the first problem.  (Hardware issues like this, unfortunately, require you to contact the system manufacturer for assistance)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hardware problem that is beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu to fix or assist with.

Answer (score 2):

Try booting a live USB or live CD of another Ubuntu version to see if the problem persists.

Chances are, though, that it is a faulty hardware problem.